# how to make collapsible/expandable views in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I created a collapsible/expandable form on android. please see GIF below

https://giphy.com/gifs/zVvcKtgT9QTaa1O29O

I'm trying to create something similar on ios, so far, i've already created the bottom sheet as seen below

[image]

Looking at this GIF https://gfycat.com/dismalbronzeblowfish, you'd notice i'm able to expand and collapse the views, but there's a big gap where the view used to be, the expected behavior is that the space collapses also with an animation

Below is the code for the bottom sheet

```
class BottomSheetViewController: UIViewController {
    // holdView can be UIImageView instead
    @IBOutlet weak var holdView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var left: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var right: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pickupView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deliveryView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deliverydetailsView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickupDetailsVIew: UIControl!
    
    
    let fullView: CGFloat = 100
    var partialView: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 300
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(BottomSheetViewController.panGesture))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        
        let pickupTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pickupButton))
        let deliveryTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(deliveryButton))
        pickupView.addGestureRecognizer(pickupTapGesture)
        deliveryView.addGestureRecognizer(deliveryTapGesture)
        
        pickupView.setBorder(radius: 5, color: .black)
        deliveryView.setBorder(radius: 5, color: .black)
        
        roundViews()
        
        deliverydetailsView.isHidden = true
        pickupDetailsVIew.isHidden = true
        
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        prepareBackgroundView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { [weak self] in
            let frame = self?.view.frame
            let yComponent = self?.partialView
            self?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yComponent!, width: frame!.width, height: frame!.height)
        })
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    @IBAction func rightButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("clicked")
    }
    
    @objc func pickupButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")
        if pickupDetailsVIew.isHidden {
            expand(pickupDetailsVIew)
            collapse(deliverydetailsView)
        } else {
            collapse(pickupDetailsVIew)
            
        }
    }
    
    @objc func deliveryButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")
        if deliverydetailsView.isHidden {
            expand(deliverydetailsView)
            collapse(pickupDetailsVIew)
        } else {
            collapse(deliverydetailsView)
            
//            if deliveryView.isHidden && pickupDetailsVIew.isHidden {
//
//            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func expand(_ view: UIView) {
        view.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func collapse(_ view: UIView) {
        view.isHidden = true
    }
    
//    @IBAction func close(_ sender: AnyObject) {
//        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
//            let frame = self.view.frame
//            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.partialView, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
//        })
//    }
    
    @objc func panGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
        let y = self.view.frame.minY
        if ( y + translation.y >= fullView) && (y + translation.y <= partialView ) {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y + translation.y, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }
        
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            var duration =  velocity.y < 0 ? Double((y - fullView) / -velocity.y) : Double((partialView - y) / velocity.y )
            
            duration = duration > 1.3 ? 1 : duration
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                if  velocity.y >= 0 {
                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.partialView, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                } else {
                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.fullView, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                }
                
                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func roundViews() {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        holdView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
//        left.layer.cornerRadius = 10
//        right.layer.cornerRadius = 10
//        left.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 148/225, blue: 247.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
//        left.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    func prepareBackgroundView(){
//        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect.init(style: .dark)
//        let visualEffect = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: blurEffect)
//        let bluredView = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: blurEffect)
//        bluredView.contentView.addSubview(visualEffect)
//
//        visualEffect.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
//        bluredView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
//
//        view.insertSubview(bluredView, at: 0)
    }

}
```

I need some help/pointers in the right direction from anyone who has done this before, or who knows how to do this

Thank you

Comment: Question? You state - and your code suggests - you are using storyboards. Are you also using auto layout at some level?

Comment: I'm using a .xib file for the bottom sheet and I'm not using auto layout with it